# git: more account/repo same machine

Tags: git

I have installed git and made an account "acc1" using repo "repo1" on the folder "folder1".

Now I have made a second repo "repo2" `https://github.com/acc2/repo2.git`
used `git config --global` to set the new user.name and email locally.
Running

```
git config -l
```

says correctly

```
user.name=acc2
user.email=acc2@second.email
```

however, if i use `git push -u origin master` it says:

```
Permission to acc2/repo2.git denied to acc1.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/acc2/repo2.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I make the second account work (without using ssh)?
I can delete the first account on the machine. I can't find where that setting is located.

Answer (score 0):

```
git config --local credential.helper ""
```

works in my case